# How can I prevent content from unauthorized views (php/js)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I prevent (unauthorized) people from reading a message on a website (e.g. by looking in the browser cache for the text/images)?**

- **It's a PUBLIC (!) site** (means: no logins here!)

But:

- the (secret) message is only shown for a certain time.
- the message might be shown only if a passwort is given.

Problems:

- In Opera for example page(=page contents/text) could be indexed by the browser and searched.
- One idea was to create an image with the message ... but: Also images - even when a header "no cache" is send could be retrieved from FireFox's cache.
- Also: Recreating the message from single characters as image does not work (at least I think so at the moment). I tried this method, but it makes output quite slow (writing this: I notice that I do not need to create the images at runtime, but could create images (of single letters) in advance and display/refer to them not by real, but pseudo random names in the HTML )
- I also had the idea to output a encoded message (ROT13) (in HTML) but use JS .onload to decode the message immediately. Problem: If this code is in the HTML it could be recovered from the cache later on. At least if someone searches through the (Opera) cache the person would probably not think of entering search terms encoded.

Programming language is PHP.

Comment: If you're using PHP, don't even write it to the client if it's not supposed to be show. Otherwise, if you do, I can find it.

Comment: 'unauthorized' in conjunction with 'no logins' & 'public', that way madness lies. Caching is up to browsers, you can only hint. I personally do not believe this can be done with any amount of reliability, any solution is probably breakable. Obfuscation can be done, but is inherently flawed.

Comment: +1 for "That Way, Madness Lies"

Comment: AJAX isn't reliable?  BRB, redesigning half the internet.... :P

Comment: @Chris: no, the security the OP is looking for isn't reliable. Ajaxy requests can also be cached, stored, etc. Don't put words in my mouth I haven't said. If you rely on ajax-requests as any form of 'security', no wonder that so many sites get hacked and/or data stolen, so by all means redesign those.

Comment: The word "security" first appears on this page in your comment.  It isn't part of the stated OP that this is supposed to be security-related.  He doesn't want something to cache, that's all. AJAX response text is not cached long-term by the browser.  Of COURSE this isn't adequate for security - but again, this isn't a security question, it is a cache question.

Comment: Well, excuse me for interpreting _'I prevent (unauthorized) people from reading a message'_ as having anything to do with security....

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What if someone takes a screenshot of this?

Comment: I think this is maybe taking his goal a little to literally.  Clearly, if it is shown on the screen, someone can look at the screen and see it, or take a screenshot, or read over someone's shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the secret code to the page with javascript, after the page is loaded.  You'd want to retrieve the secret code via AJAX, then write it to the page - that way, the code isn't cached in the HTML part of the source, and it isn't sitting in the javascript within the page's source code.

Content piped in with AJAX is pretty ephemeral, it won't be cached or otherwise recorded.

Since I don't know anything about your HTML or what (if any) javascript framework you might be using, I can't give you a code sample, but you should be able to work with the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically if it is sent to the client and displayed on screen then you can not prevent the message from being saved or stored on the client machine. Whatever you do to prevent that save could still be bypassed by a simple screenshot.

If you are not concerned about the person the message is targeted at saving said message then I think your best course of action would be to use Flash with Flash doing a call to the server to retrieve the message and display it. Another option may be to use javascript to perform some form of call (AJAX) to the server which then sends back the message and you alter the DOM to display the message. I don't think that would be cached but unless you use SSL it could be stored by intermediate proxies.

Comment: Why use Flash to do AJAX when you can just do AJAX from native javascript?  Right idea on the mechanics, but adding Flash to implement it is way overboard.

Comment: I think the purpose of using Flash here is to prevent the user from selecting and copying the text.  I'm not sure, but I think he's also suggesting that Flash has a greater degree of control over caching than Ajax.

Comment: Either method would be reasonable but flash may be favoured if you don't want to do any calls back to the server. Flash could do the password validation and display the message. However the message could still be retrieved by examining the cached flash file if technically skilled and so inclined. And as Phoenix said it adds another layer of difficulty to saving the final message. I don't think it would add any further degree of control over caching compared to ajax - although my comment regarding proxy servers stands.